# Updating the timestamp of many "old" files with Google Drive API

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api

I wrote a Google script to update the timestamp of my Google Drive files more than 920 days old. It worked fine at the start, but as the file numbers increased I got script timeout issues. Any suggestions to optimize the script would be appreciated

```
function listOldFiles() {
  var files = DriveApp.getFiles();
  var today = new Date();
  var offsetDate = today.setDate(today.getDate() - 920);
  while ( files.hasNext() ) {
    var file = files.next();
    var cdate = file.getLastUpdated();
    Logger.log(cdate);
    if (cdate.valueOf() < offsetDate) {
      var fileid = file.getId();
      Drive.Files.touch(fileid);
    }    
  }
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to use `searchFiles` instead? It would decrease the number of loops. [Documentation here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/drive-app#searchFiles(String))

Answer (score 0):

As suggested above, you can use 'searchFiles()' to make the linked file list (FileIterator) smaller. Your script may still time out if the search query returns a large number of files. 
If that's the case, you could monitor execution time and store continuation tokens for file iterator between runs.

```
function processFiles() {

 var startTimeInMillisec = new Date().getTime();

  var triggers = ScriptApp.getProjectTriggers();

  for (var i=0; i < triggers.length; i++) { //delete previosuly created triggers

       ScriptApp.deleteTrigger(triggers[i]);     

   }
  var props = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties();
  var continuationToken = props.getProperty("continuationToken");
  var files = (continuationToken) ? DriveApp.continueFileIterator(continuationToken) : DriveApp.getFiles();


while (files.hasNext()) {

  //do something

  var elapsedTimeInMillisec = new Date().getTime() - startTimeInMillisec;

  if (elapsedTimeInMillisec > 290000) { // execution time nearing 5 mintues

    continuationToken = files.getContinuationToken();
    props.setProperty("continuationToken", continuationToken);

    ScriptApp.newTrigger("processFiles")
             .timeBased()
             .after(300000)
             .create();
    return;

  }

}

}
```

Comment: If he uses the search method to find old files, by virtue of updating files he will shrink the loop anyway, and a continuation token will not be needed.

Comment: @tehhowch yes, but what if he has lots of files older than 920 days? It's at least worth considering

Comment: When he re-runs the script the next time, all the files previously matching the "updated > 920 days ago" query that were modified will no longer match it. :) This is something that is unique to this type of query, and in general, I agree a continuation token is a good practice

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. Implemented above, timed out the first time, but have been running fine ever since.